# Change colour of frame title in beamer article

Tags: beamer, frame-title, beamerarticle

I'm using the beamerarticle package and I would like to change the colour of the text that I give as the frame title. In the MEW below,

```
\documentclass[17pt]{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ABC}
    a
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like the ABC to be printed in red. However, even after inserting the setbeamercolor command, it's still coming in black. I would appreciate help in resolving this.

EDIT: Yes, one option is that I manually use the color package in each title, but I would like to automate this so that with one command in one place, the color of each frame title can be changed, and I need not insert the color package command in each frametitle command I use.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22768/how-to-use-beamer-colors-in-beamerarticle/27309 ?

Comment: Firstly, the `color` package is not used.  with one command in one place, the color of each frame title can be changed - this is confusing. You need to tell the system which color to use for the frame title, right? In that case even to the new command, you need to pass the required color. If all frame titles are to be in red, that can be automated. Kindly clarify

Comment: Yes I want all frame titles to be in red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach could be to modify the beamer template for the frametitle:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<article>{
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\paragraph*{\color{red}\insertframetitle}\ \par\noindent\emph{\insertframesubtitle}\par}
}
\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ABC}
    a
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you add to your answer an explanation on how your command works also? That way I can modify it further.

Comment: @AnantJoshi The command is copied from `beamerbasearticle.sty`, I just added the `\color{red}` command

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `\textcolor{<required color>}{text}`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textcolor{red}{ABC}}
    a
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To automate the process, to ensure all frame titles are in red, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\newcommand{\myframetitle}[1]{\frametitle{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\begin{frame}
\myframetitle{ABC} 
    a
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can define a new command `\myframetitle` in this case to meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to automate this process though.

Comment: @subhamsoni Technically it *is* right, but isn't there really a better way? ;-)

Comment: @AnantJoshi what do you mean by automate the process. You mean a new command?

Comment: Yes I have edited the question suitably.

Comment: @AnantJoshi I have updated my answer.